# Lua can't decode google Sheet JSON?

Tags: json, lua, google-sheets, coronasdk

I'm trying to decode a JSON string in Corona, using Lua. json.decode seems to work for older google sheets, but not for newer ones -- instead of a string of JSON data, I seem to get a lot of HTML and who knows what. It looks like this:

http://pastebin.com/rXVi5UBC

Am I getting a 404 webpage, or am I missing something? Is there some recent change to google sheets API that would have caused my data not to come down? I'm trying to parse a document like this by using the standard Lua json:decode() function.

S

Comment: The content at that link certainly isn't json. It is an HTML page. From the title it looks like some toplevel Google Sheets page. So it sounds like whatever you are doing to fetch the sheet in question isn't working. Authentication problem perhaps?

Comment: Yes! Agreed. It wasn't an authentication problem, though, because I knew I was getting to the sheet -- just the response was empty (nil). Anyway, I figured out the answer! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the reason why it wasn't working -- turns out NEW google sheets documents need to be "published" in order to be accessed via the API.

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/37579?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

(Apologies it would not allow me to comment...)

I'm trying to do a similar reading of the JSON in a google spreadsheet. Could you explain how you exported it into JSON and some other steps you followed? I can't seem to get it just right...

Comment: Create a different question, and I'll see what I can do. I won't post the answer in this question -- just give me a link.